# How to enable push notification in quickblox groupchat

Tags: android, notifications, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have been trying quickblox chat api and i have gotten stucked at some place.
I have registered and setup gcm notifications and i am able to received notifications that are been sent from Google Developer Console.
I am able to receive notifications that are sent from QuickBlox Admin panel. I subscribe to notifications each time the activity is started and am able to receive messages that are sent on the group chat but if i go offline, i do not receive notifications when the messages are sent. I don't know if i have to register the groupchat for notificatons in some way. Please what do i do to be able to receive notifications when the app is closed or when the user was offline and messages were sent.